# Autoresizing UItextview in ios7 for a messaging like app

Tags: ios7, uitextfield, uitextview, messaging

I need help with an autoresizing `UITextView`. I am building an SMS like application.

I used following code to do this :

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    CGRect frame = textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
    textView.frame = frame;
}
```

what happens is the `UITextView` does expand but it expands below the keyboard. I want it to expand upwards, like the way it does on the messages app. I tried googling for help but didn't find much out there. any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

see in this url for custom textview github download it add it ur project

link: https://github.com/HansPinckaers/GrowingTextView

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. It works like a charm. Only problem is what ever was on the view controller before is not being displayed. For example if you had an image, u can't see it. Its just a plain white screen with the keyboard and the uitextview on top of it. Would you happen to know whats going on by any chance?